# How do I create two years comparison sales query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product and sales table. The sales table has the product id as a foreign key with sales date and quantity sold for each product. I want to generate a yearly comparison report based on the product quantity sold. So the report will have all the products with year like 2019 and 2020 with the sum of quantity for each product displaying below 2019 and 2020.
I have written this query and is not working.

```
 select p.name, sum(s.quantity) as qty from products as p 
    left join sales as s
   
    on s.product_id = p.id
      where s.year == '2019' and s.year == '2020' group by p.name, s.quantity
```

Comment: If you want to group by year, why don't I see year in the `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need  both the year you should use OR and not AND

```
    select s.year, p.name, sum(s.quantity) as qty 
    from products as p 
    left join sales as s on s.product_id = p.id
         AND  s.year = '2019' OR  s.year == '2020' 
    group by p.name,s.year
```

and you should not use  quantity in group by

but for comparision could be you need

```
    select  p.name, sum(s1.quantity) qty_2019, sum(s2.quantity) qty_2020
    from products as p 
    left join sales s1 as s on s1.product_id = p.id 
        AND s1.year = '2019' 
    left join sales s2 as s on s2.product_id = p.id 
        AND s1.year = '2020'        group by p.name,s.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.name,
       sum(case when s.year = 2019 then s.quantity end) as qty_2019,
       sum(case when s.year = 2020 then s.quantity end) as qty_2020,
from products as p left join
     sales as s   
     on s.product_id = p.id
group by p.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

I take it you want two sums, one for each year, not a sum for the total of two years.  There are a couple of ways to do that.  One would be to calculate the two sums as separate subqueries, and JOIN them:

```
SELECT a.name, a.sum AS sum2020, b.sum AS sum2019
FROM
  (select name, sum(quantity) AS sum from Products as P LEFT JOIN Sales AS S ON S.product_id = P.id where S.year = '2020') a
  JOIN
  (select name, sum(quantity) AS sum from Products as P LEFT JOIN Sales AS S ON S.product_id = P.id where S.year = '2019') b
  ON a.name = b.name;
```

The other would be a single query that calculates two sums of conditional columns.

```
SELECT name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN S.year = '2020' THEN S.quantity ELSE 0 END) sum2020,
   SUM(CASE WHEN S.year = '2019' THEN S.quantity ELSE 0 END) sum2019,
FROM Products P
   LEFT JOIN Sales S
   ON S.product_id = P.id
   GROUP BY P.name
```

I don't know which is faster, and different people may find one approach or the other more conceptually simple.

By the way, with a query like this, I like to start by generating the sequence of years, CROSS JOIN the product ids, and then LEFT JOIN the yearly totals to that cross product.  That way, you get the whole matrix of year*product and can put in zeroes where there's no data.  Without doing this, you could have gaps in the data where a certain product had zero sales for a year, resulting in misleading reports or charts and graphs with odd scales.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN s... WHERE s =...` is oxymoronic

Comment: It's `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...`.  Not `WHERE`.  Not sure what you mean -- are you saying MySQL will automatically infer the join terms?

Comment: I know what it is. Run EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query] followed By SHOW WARNINGS